# PHP MYSQL Variable returns error

Tags: php, mysql

Simple question, but my searching is not finding an answer. I am trying to use a variable in a MySQL search and I keep getting an error. I know the variable value is good because when I pass it directly it works. Here is the error I get

`"Error: something went wrong: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Bank of CanadaGROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date) DESC' at line "`

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM current_rates WHERE 
financial_institution =". $lenderName .
"GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date) DESC";
```

Comment: you need a space before GROUP. and please for the question properly

Comment: Thank you made the change and still gett error. My variable is set to lenderName = 'Royal Bank of Canada'; and the error message drops the first word for some reason.

Answer (score 5):

Strings in MySQL must be enclosed with single quotes.

Otherwise, they will be considered as **reserved words**/**column names**.

The corrected SQL should be:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM current_rates WHERE 
 financial_institution ='". $lenderName .
 "' GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date) DESC";
```

Also, as per answer from **Bhaumik Mehta**, you need to add a space before `GROUP BY` tag.

Answer (score 3):

Try this query:

1) You need to enclose `$lenderName` in `''` as the it is a `string` value.

2) You need to have space before `GROUP  BY` keyword

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM current_rates WHERE financial_institution ='". $lenderName ."' GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date) DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

please given one space between name and group

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM current_rates WHERE financial_institution ='".$lenderName."' GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date) DESC";
```